# How to use "INSERT (name, ...) INTO table SELECT name, ... FROM table_2" to only insert rows who don't have the same 'NAME'?

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day/Afternoon/Evening/Night.

I want to know if it's possible to insert rows from table_1 into table_2 only if the rows from table_1 don't have the same name.

I know about `IF NOT EXISTS` but that's not what I'm looking for.

I have multiple rows who have the same name like this:

table: players

```
|ID | Name | Chance |
|---|------|--------| 
| 1 | Test1|  40    |
| 2 | Test1|  30    |
| 3 | Test2|  30    |
| 4 | Test2|  30    |
```

This is what I'm using:

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO user_items (card_img, name, rating, price, position, club, club_img, country, country_img, card_type, walkout_img, chance, user_id) 
SELECT card_img
     , name
     , rating
     , price
     , position
     , club
     , club_img
     , country
     , country_img
     , card_type
     , walkout_img
     , chance
     , id
  FROM players
     , users 
 ORDER 
    BY -LOG(1+RAND())*chance 
 LIMIT 4";
```

Comment: I'm a little lost.  You mention two tables but only show one.  You say "the same name".  The same name as what?

Comment: Your query and your data do not relate (there are two tables and multiple columns in your query), which makes your question hard to understand.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated my post

Comment: @GMB I have updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join with a subquery that selects the names in `players` that aren't repeated.

```
INSERT INTO user_items (card_img, name, rating, price, position, club, club_img, country, country_img, card_type, walkout_img, chance, user_id) 
SELECT card_img, players.name, rating, price, position, club, club_img, country, country_img, card_type, walkout_img, chance, id 
FROM players
JOIN (
    SELECT name
    FROM players
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS single_players ON players.name = single_players.name
CROSS JOIN users 
ORDER BY -LOG(1+RAND())*chance 
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: I get this error: Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous in C:\xampp\htdocs\store\insert.php:33 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\store\insert.php(33): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO use...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\store\insert.php on line 33

Comment: Needed to qualify `name` to `players.name`.

Comment: Thank you! Can you perhaps also post a `JOIN` with a subquery that selects the names in players and inserts them but not all the repeated ones? like this: [non-repeated names] and one Test1 and Test2 or [non-repeated names] and one Test1/Test2.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. Do you mean you just want one row inserted for every player, whether they're repeated or not?